# Fast fourier transformation in python using scipy

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft, scientific-computing

I am using scipy.fft module for calculating Fourier transformation of an array. Now using the module I got the transformation. But my question is how do I know the elements in the transformed array corresponds to which frequency.
In short, the module scipy.fft.fft takes an array as input, how it knows that at which frequencies transformation has to be determined.

Comment: Not sure I totally understand what this means: `"how it knows that at which frequencies transformation has to be determined."`. Seems like you're essentially asking, "How does the FFT work?" which is beyond the scope of SO and belongs on math.SE.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The [`scipy.fft.fftfreq()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fft.fftfreq.html#scipy.fft.fftfreq) helper function calculates the frequencies corresponding to the discrete values in the array returned by `scipy.fft.fft()`.

As an example, assume that you have a signal sampled every 0.25 seconds and it is 10 samples long:

```
from scipy import fft

n = 10  # number of samples
d = 0.25  # sample spacing

frequencies = fft.fftfreq(n, d)
print(frequencies)
```

which outputs:

```
[ 0.   0.4  0.8  1.2  1.6 -2.  -1.6 -1.2 -0.8 -0.4]
```

These correspond to the center frequencies of the bins in your transformed array.

Comment: Thanks for your response, however it still does not answer my question. The function fftfreq takes two argument (one is sample size and other is sample spacing). Now if we change the sample spacing the value of output array of frequencies changes. Although, In case of fft function it only takes input as the input array, so apparently it only knows the number of sample it does not know the sample spacing, but it still does the transformation. How??